# Jqgrid - intercept on edit to turn empty to 0

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way in Jqgrid to intercept the edit event and to turn the empty string into 0 before going to the server?

Comment: Could you describe more detailed what you need? Which jqGrid **version** you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which editing mode you use (inline editing, form editing or cell editing) and in which form (for example inline editing via `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav` or direct call of `editRow`)? What you exactly mean under "intercept" of editing events? Do you mean callbacks or jQuery events (`onSelectRow` or `jqGridSelectRow`)?

Comment: Hi Oleg, we are still using the older fork. Basically what I need the grid to do is to replace the value of the cell to 0 when the user leaves it blank. I have to do this on the client because there are other rules on top of that. Is it possible to intercept that value somewhere and replace it manually with 0?

Comment: I am using inline editing via formatter in a older free version of Jqgrid. it appears to be no way to change the value anywhere

Comment: Oleg, I ended up usinf required:true field. I think it's the easiest way that fits in with the way we do it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I suppose that you use wrong terminology: inline editing via formatter sounds wrong. I suggest you to post some code fragments, which shows *how you use* inline editing, instead of discussion about terminology. Please include *always* the exact version of jqGrid, which you use. It's important for other readers. You wrote in some old questions about v4.4.4. Is it still so? The callbacks are *different* in different jqGrid versions. Additionally many formatters supports `defaultValue` property. Other option will be the usage of `aftersavefunc` callback, but I need to know details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand a inline edit with formater actions is used.

I think that one possible solution is to use serializeRowData grid option, where we can modify any parameter before it is post to the server when inline edit is on. It can look like this

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
...
    serializeRowData : function(postdata) {
        for (var key in postadata) {
            if(postdata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if(postdata[key] === '') {
                    postdata[key] = 0;
                }

            }
        }
        return postdata;
    },
...
});
```